# editable field with in svg

Tags: svg, textbox

I am trying to provide edit option for label inside svg element using text box with in foreign object.
If text written in the text box is larger than width of the text box,text given overflows outer the text box field.

```html
<svg>
  <foreignObject x="30" y="15" width="200" height="40" class="editable" style="cursor: default;">
   <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <input type="text" class="editable-div" style="width:120px;">
  </div>
  </foreignObject>
  </svg>
```

[image]

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kL8wyw3s/3/)

Comment: Which browser are you using?  I see noting like what you describe in FF or Chrome.

Comment: In chrome type more text to reproduce in the sample given above.

Comment: I typed a couple of hundred chars without problem. How many am I supposed to type? :)

Comment: Hi Paul,Facing issue in my browser only. thanks :)